# Can we convert xlsm to xlsx using POI apache

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xlsm

It is possible to convert xlsm file to xlsx file using Apache poi. I am trying to writing a xlsm file but after writing i want it to be converted into xlsx file. can you give me any solution.

Answer (score 1):

xlsm means that the Excel Workbook containts macros (VBA code)

If you want to save that workbook as an xlsx (an Excel Workbook WITHOUT macros), Excel will notice and will REMOVE all VBA code.

So, there's no point in saving as xlsm to an xlsx (as all VBA code will be removed), unless you have no VBA code in your xlsm (and then there's no point to using a xlsm in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

With Excel save .xlsm version as .xlsx .